# "Нам нужен мир и(,) желательно(,) весь": нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Начала писать эту общеизвестную фразу и меня заклинило: берется тут в запятые "желательно" или нет?)))
Буду благодарна за подсказку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы поставил здесь запятую только после слова "мир", так как далее идет присоединительная конструкция, где союз "и" употребляется в значении "и притом"